# Spring MVC 3, applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

What's wrong with the below config file. Its the applicationContex.xml give a syntext error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

        <security:http auto-config='true'>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:http>
  </beans>
```

I have added the spring-security-config-3.1.0.RC1.jar and spring-security-web-3.1.0.RC1.jar anything I am missing?

Comment: please also post the syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix the `<http>` and `<intercept-url>` tags with the security namespace:

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: Now it says failed to read scema document. I have added the spring-security-config-3.1.0.RC1.jar and spring-security-web-3.1.0.RC1.jar anything I am missing?